# In Meteor, the Images collection is undefined in the FS.Store.GridFS transformWrite function

Tags: javascript, meteor, compilation, scope, collectionfs

In the `/Project/lib` folder, I first declare an FS.Store.GridFS:

```
imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images", {
    transformWrite: function(file, readStream, writeStream){
        if (something) {...}
        else {
            Images.remove({_id: file._id});
        }
    }
}
```

Then I declare the Image collection:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
   stores: imageStore
});
```

However, upon compilation, I get the error:

```
=> Exited with code: 8
...
W20150623-13:06:51.855(-4)? (STDERR)            throw(ex);
W20150623-13:06:51.855(-4)? (STDERR)                ^
W20150623-13:06:51.855(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Images is not defined
...
```

I have tried placing the imageStore declaration inside the Images declaration, with no success.

But **importantly**, it is not only `Images` that is causing an error for being undefined. If I include *any* variable name, it appears to be undefined within that `else` statement.

On top of all of this, the exact code works for my friend...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that it works for your friend but not you, it's probably not an issue with the code itself. Try running `meteor reset`.